# How to monitor TCP and UDP port changes

Tags: port, monitoring, tcp, tcpip, udp

I am running software on a server that may be turning off some ports and need to find out what it is.  I have the ports I need to check.  I just need to find out what is turning them off.  How can I do this?

Comment: Software recommendations are off topic, and it may have been considered that is what you were after. I edited your question to ensure it's on topic for you, if you don't like it, roll it back :)

Comment: scheduled scans with nessus would at least show you the changes, though it would provide little input as to why they had changed. I assume you've tried `netstat -ntlup` and lsof right?

Comment: What kind of server?  Windows? Linux?  Toaster?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Windows, you can use [Tcpview](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897437), a very convenient utility developed by Mark Russinovih before he became VP of Microsoft. It will refresh itself every 2 (??) seconds.

If you are on Linux, the command

```
 sudo ss -ntp
```

will show you all connected ports, except for those where your system is listening, which are instead displayed by the command

```
 sudo ss -lntp
```

Both commands show the process and Process ID which is using the port in question. If you wish to monitor your ports continuously, the command is

```
 sudo watch ss -ntp
```

and likewise for the other version: it will refresh itself every two seconds.

On Mac OS, you use

```
sudo lsof -n -i4TCP:$PORT | grep LISTEN
```

or some slight variant, depending on the exact version of your OS, as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421633/who-is-listening-on-a-given-tcp-port-on-mac-os-x).